# Vimeo embed on Squarespace: hide controls on load, show on hover

Tags: iframe, vimeo, squarespace, vimeo-player

New Squarespace, Vimeo, and iFrame user here. I'm doing some work for a non-profit, and they've asked me to create a "Testimonials" page with ~10 videos where the controls of each are revealed only on hover.

### On load / inactive state

When the video loads, there shouldn't be any controls; sharing; or title/byline visible.

[image: on load]

### On hover

On hover, the user should see the player controls.

[image: on hover]

### What I've tried

Given the basic iFrame embed code:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/58659769" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

- ✅`?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0` gets rid of the title, owner name, and owner avatar of Vimeo accounts, regardless of paid status. This is a step in the right direction!
- `?controls=0` gets rid of all controls for Pro+ videos, which is the desired start state. However, the only way to then play the videos is via `autoplay=1`: https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk/embed. This wouldn't work with multiple videos on the page. Also, we don't have a paid Vimeo account.
- Targeting the elements with a `{ display: none; }` works when in my Dev Tools Panel after page load. However, I can't produce the same effect via the Custom CSS panel -- I suspect due to Vimeo server-side restrictions. (It hides the elements at first, then renders them after ~3 seconds.)
- I can't inject custom Javascript into the site via Developer Mode because we're only using the basic Squarespace, so all JS solutions are currently blocked. However, I may be able to get them to pay to upgrade Squarespace, so JS solutions are welcome!
- Injecting `<script>` tags into the embed modal doesn't execute the code

I know this would be possible from the Vimeo development side because the desired event happens when I've started to play the video. After pausing a video that has been playing, the controls disappear, and then reappear on mouse movement over the video.

The closest thing I could find was using Frogaloop (https://forum.webflow.com/t/play-vimeo-video-on-hover-from-a-cms-collection/78458). However, given JavaScript restrictions, I don't know how to execute something similar in Squarespace.

#### Credit

The video stills are just for testing, given that I know that it is uploaded to a user with a Vimeo Plus account. Thanks to Bianca Giaever! https://vimeo.com/58659769

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to connect with the folks on the [@VimeoStaff](https://twitter.com/VimeoStaff) Twitter account, who provided me with the following answer. **TL;DR: what I'm attempting to do isn't possible, but there are some (suboptimal) workarounds.**

> As you've found, you can control settings individually (such as the
>   title and byline) within the Embed tab of your video settings page.
>
> I'm afraid it's not possible to change anything mid-load in JS,
>   meaning you won't be able to load the player with no controls and then
>   activate them with a hover. We're so sorry for any inconvenience! I'll
>   be sure to extend this feedback to our product team.
>
> It is possible to remove the playbar from your embedded videos. You
>   can enable this feature by adding the ?background=1 parameter to the
>   end of the player URL in your embed code, for example:
>
> ```
> <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871?background=1"
> width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen"
> allowfullscreen></iframe>
> ```
>
> Adding this parameter will have the following effect:
>
> - All player toggles and elements will be turned off (including the play/pause button!)
> - The video will automatically loop.
> - The video will be set to autoplay
> - The video will be muted
>
> If you would simply like to hide the UI of the player without
>   muting/autoplaying/looping (i.e for a chromeless player), you can
>   alternatively add the controls=0 to the end of the player URL in your
>   embed code, for example:
>
> ```
> <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871?controls=0"
> width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen"
> allowfullscreen></iframe>
> ```
>
> When using the controls embed parameter, you'll need to either enable
>   autoplay (?autoplay=1), use keyboard shortcuts, or implement our
>   player SDK to start and control playback.
>
> More information on background and chromeless videos can be found
>   here. Please note that keyboard shortcuts cannot be disabled
>   currently.
>
> Additionally, I can see you've mentioned having multiple videos on one
>   page. If you have more than one video autoplaying on a particular
>   page, you will also need to include this parameter: autopause=0